# Using Xpath contains and string() to get the innermost node

Tags: xpath

Here is the html:

```
<div id="div_1">
   <div id="div_2">
     <span>today</span>
     <span>tomorror</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the innermost node whose children nodes contains the string 'todaytomorrow'

I can use $x('//*[contains(string(), "todaytomorrow")]'), but the div_1 and div_2 are both returned. So how can I return the only div_2 which is the innermost node?

Comment: `//*[*[text() = 'today' ] and *[text() = 'tomorrow' ]]`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how the XPath expression you tried is actually producing the result stated without accounting for whitespace unless you formatted the XML differently in the question.  This version of the initial attempt produces the stated undesirable result.

```
//*[contains(normalize-space(string()), "today tomorrow")]
```

You can modify this with a predicate to eliminate all but the last selected node:

```
(//*[contains(normalize-space(string()), "today tomorrow")])[last()]
```

If the original XPath expression is really selecting both nodes for you, then you can modify that original expression like:

```
(//*[contains(string(), "todaytomorrow")])[last()]
```

As suggested in other comments, there are a definitely other solutions such as those taking advantage of the differences between text() and string() node tests.